# What is the function of the F8 key?

Tags: security

I know absolutely NOTHING about computers. What is the function of the F8 key and what do I do if an outside source locks my computer and demands money for unlocking?

Comment: This sounds like two questions. Are they somehow related - eg; has someone threatened to lock your computer, and mentioned the F8 key?

Comment: Welcome to superuser!  Please tell us a bit more about your situation, so that we can help you!

Comment: Maybe you are referring to a virus like [this one](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/38039/remove-latest-fbi-money-pack-virus-despite-safe-mode-forced-restart/), which can be removed by starting the computer in “Safe Mode with Command Prompt”. As JDH says in his answer below, the way to do that is by hitting the F8 key on startup.

Comment: Thanks for posting! We'll need a bit more details to answer your question though. Can you provide us a few more, otherwise we will be guessing since F8 can do different things depending on context.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the top row "F" keys are used differently depending on what application is running. However, at bootup time on windows, if you hit f8 several times, after powering up and before windows starts, you can get a boot menu. One important boot option there is "Safe mode", which allows booting with only known windows driver without any other add-ons. (I like to call this "safe boot").

For the demand for money, clearly that's a blackmail scam. Don't listen to them. Get someone knowledgeable to help you out. See the link by @garrulinae above for help links.

Comment: "Safe boot" is called "safe _mode_" in Windows 7 and previous (I don't know what it is in Windows 8, but if it says "Safe Mode" and not "Safe boot", that's OK)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question "what do I do if an outside source locks my computer and demands money for unlocking?":

At that point you don't respond to them in any way. First of all there's no guarantee that paying will actually get your PC unlocked (there's no honor among thieves), and secondly by paying you will be contributing to maintaining a criminal infostructure - these ransomware demands only exist because people pay.

You take your measures **beforehand**: have good backups in place, on- and offline. There's plenty of info around of good backup schemes. Then, should this scenario happen, you (have someone) wipe your hard disk clean and reinstall everything from the backups.

And remember that ransomware generally only gets on your computer if you click on weird links on websites or in emails ("OMG Look at how this girl committed suicide", "Justin Bieber naked pics", "iPhone 7 deals: only $50 when importing directly"). If you have email coming in that you don't recognize, delete it without opening.